# Problem with my google map, place search with a text bar

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api, angularjs

I am doing a small project with google maps api, I am trying to locate all the interesting services around me. For example, i want to search "restaurant" then it will shows all the restaurant near me within my radius.

Javascript framework that I am using

1. Ionic framework
2. Angular JS
3. Google maps API

Here's the link, it won't shows the result since either you have to run it on localhost or have an emulator to run it.

http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=DhsmJ98GNe

Comment: You need the Google Places API to filter points of interest see the first example https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox and search for "restaurants"